# Which application needs a client secret, web, SPA, API (like dotnet core web api)?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, secret-key

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) explains how to register a web application. It's no clear whether by web, it includes SPA (Angular and React) and API (something like Dotnet core web API). Even this [sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) on doesn't contains a secret.

My understanding is the secret is like a password for an application. However, which type of application needs it, server side web application (ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WEB API), SPA like Angular?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never put a secret in a SPA.
It will be visible to anyone who looks at the app.
The same applies to any other "public client application", i.e. an app that runs on a user's device.

A back-end server application needs a secret or certificate when it needs to authenticate itself to the identity provider.
So if the back-end app needs to get access tokens, it'll need a secret.

An ASP.NET Web API might not need a secret for example.
If it does not call any downstream APIs, it only needs to validate incoming tokens, which it can do without a secret.

Comment: just to be clear and avoid the confusion I'm having. By `backend server`,  you mean something like ASP.NET MVC that runs in the server then return the response to the browser as HTML?

Comment: Yes. An app that runs in an environment you trust can use secrets :)